# how to correctly return public server address in EC2 instance with PHP

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, php-fpm, php7

I'm new with AWS...
I have set up one EC2 instance where it runs Nginx and PHP 7.1.6
i have also made a page that return `phpinfo();` details but it returning not my elastic IP but internal IP address:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] 172.31.9.228
```

My EC2 has correctly associated one elastic IP and also trying browsing website everything running smooth.

There is a way to let Nginx returns public IP instead of private one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EIP is not binded to any network interfaces.

The easiest way to get the EIP is through the instance's [metedata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval).

```
$eip = file_get_contents('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4');
```